# Fix "Unable to check the status of the firewall" of `Set-WSManQuickConfig`

Tags: powershell, azure

Why `Enable-PSRemoting`/`Set-WSManQuickConfig` can not "check the status of the firewall" running under Administrator on Windows 2012R2, Azure WebRole? How to fix this?

```
PS D:\Users\***User> enable-psremoting -force

WinRM is already set up to receive requests on this computer.
Set-WSManQuickConfig : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2"
Machine="localhost"><f:Message><f:ProviderFault provider="Config provider"
path="%systemroot%\system32\WsmSvc.dll"><f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault"
Code="2" Machine="RD***CA2"><f:Message>Unable to check the status of the firewall.
</f:Message></f:WSManFault></f:ProviderFault></f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:69 char:17
+                 Set-WSManQuickConfig -force
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WSManQuickConfig], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.SetWSManQuickConfigCommand
```

OS Name: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter. OS Version: 6.3.9600 N/A Build 9600. Powershell: 4.0

PS.
Yes, there are:

- [Error PSRemoting using Session and CredSSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908738/error-psremoting-using-session-and-credssp). No clear solution
- [Winrm quick config shows error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222837/winrm-quick-config-shows-error) . Rebooting/reimaging the instance does not help.
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2697738. Hotfix (2012 year!) is not installed but then it needs installed each deployment?
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849694.aspx. Has this message but that is for "client versions"
- http://terenceluk.blogspot.ru/2012/05/executing-command-winrm-quickconfig.html Restarting firewall does not help
- [How to enable powershell remoting in Powershell V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653879/how-to-enable-powershell-remoting-in-powershell-v3). No "HKLM:\SYSTEM\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Firewall" to change. restarting firewall service does not help.

Update.
Other valuable refs:

- http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2011/01/quick-powershell-remoting-guide/
- http://www.davidaiken.com/2011/01/12/enable-powershell-remoting-on-windows-azure/
- Get-Help about_Remote_Troubleshooting

Answer (score 12):

In my case running this helped (manually creates the firewall rule):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" dir=in action=allow service=any enable=yes profile=any localport=5985 protocol=tcp
```

Taken from http://www.davidaiken.com/2011/01/12/enable-powershell-remoting-on-windows-azure/

Answer (score 1):

I tried to enable winrm for ansible testing, nothing helped, the rules were in place. Changing the Windows display language from czech to english fixed my problem.